# Join two columns with IDs on different rows

Tags: mysql

## Problem description

I try to join or select unique rows from the same table from different columns and rows. The unique ID exists in both Column cPlayerA and cPlayerB. The table can grow dynamically and I cannot hard code the SQL.

## Table Structure and data

```
CREATE TABLE tJoinTwoColumn(
cId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
cPlayerA int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
cPlayerB int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (cId)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

#insert data
INSERT INTO tJoinTwoColumn (cId,cPlayerA,cPlayerB) VALUES (1,2001,1001);
INSERT INTO tJoinTwoColumn (cId,cPlayerA,cPlayerB) VALUES (2,1001,2001);
INSERT INTO tJoinTwoColumn (cId,cPlayerA,cPlayerB) VALUES (3,4001,3001);
INSERT INTO tJoinTwoColumn (cId,cPlayerA,cPlayerB) VALUES (4,3001,4001);

select * from tJoinTwoColumn;
```

## Data returned

Shows what is selected and what I need to filter away

[image: Shows what is selected and what I need to filter away]

## Code I tried

```
select distinct t1.cPlayerA , t1.cPlayerB  from tJoinTwoColumn t1
join  tJoinTwoColumn t2 on t1.cPlayerA = t2.cPlayerB
group by t1.cPlayerA , t1.cPlayerB;
```

But it returns 4 rows when I want to return only 2 rows in above example
I would like row 2 and 4 to be filtered out in the select.

Is this possible?

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow . please tell me for details for best solution  for you

Comment: yes it's possible with SQL but tell more

Comment: Are you looking for JOIN ? Please explain better what do you want and what you actually get. Please post your code also into a [mcve]

Comment: How do you decide which rows belong in the output?

Comment: Specific filter please.

Comment: `SELECT cData1, cData2 FROM table WHERE cData1 < cData2` will give shown output records on shown data.

Comment: Hi. I don't have access to the code right now. But the query needs to be dynamic as I dont know how many rows the table will end up with. So hard is not an option.
Basically I just want to lookup a list from the database that not duplicates the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `not exists` with an inequality condition on `id`:

```
select t.*
from tJoinTwoColumn t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tJoinTwoColumn t1
    where 
        least(t1.cPlayerA, t1.cPlayerB) = least(t.cPlayerA, t.cPlayerB)
        and greatest(t1.cPlayerA, t1.cPlayerB) = greatest(t.cPlayerA, t.cPlayerB)
        and t1.cId < t.cId
)
```

This will filter out true duplicates and "mirror" records, keeping the one that has the smallest `id`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d73f1f9ecd21bd7028d2c8d949c78d2e)**:

```
cId | cPlayerA | cPlayerB
--: | -------: | -------:
  1 |     2001 |     1001
  3 |     4001 |     3001
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thought this was impossible. A big thanks!

Comment: Done. Was a bit difficult to find.. It was my first question...

Answer (score -1):

My even odd technique, try this query hope full will work for you

```
SELECT 
datta.cId, datta.cPlayerA, datta.cPlayerB
FROM (



SELECT ad.*,

@removed := (if (@removed=0, if( @removed=1, 0, 1 )  , 0) ) AS Will_be_removed

FROM (


select  * from tJoinTwoColumn t1



 ) AS ad

 JOIN (SELECT @removed:=0) AS removed


 ) AS datta


  WHERE datta.Will_be_removed = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but not sure this will work because the table will grow and this has to be dynamic. 
Think like this.
1. User1 buy a ticket and select connection with other User2
2. User2 buy a ticket and select connection with User1

Data:
ID / USER1_ID / USER2_ID
1 / 10 / 11
2 / 11 / 10

Now in the app I only want to show one row
User1 is connected with User2

Dont want to show User2 is connected with User1
Hope this clarifies.
Thanks